# Нейросеть и python

Tags: python

Вопрос странный, но всё же.

Есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки нейросетей для python'a, чтобы не заморачиваться с математикой? Грубо говоря, чтоб был принцип "входные данные и выходные" с возможностью тренировки

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, что значит "не заморачиваться с математикой", но есть хорошая библиотека PyBrain. https://habrahabr.ru/post/148407/

Answer (score 0):

Вот держи https://github.com/sozykin/dlpython_course/blob/master/computer_vision/foto_comparison/foto_verification.ipynb

Тут рассматриваться на примере анализа фото.

Answer (score 0):

чтоб совсем не заморачиваться конечно нет, но есть [keras](https://pypi.org/project/Keras/), это надстройка над другими библиотеками, где заморочек много больше, [Вот тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GX7qxV5nh5o&list=PLtPJ9lKvJ4oiz9aaL_xcZd-x0qd8G0VN_), есть гайд по нейросетям, с использованием keras